# grep all, a noop with grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tail

I have a command like so:

```
foobar &> my.log
```

and then I tail the log file with:

```
tail -F my.log | grep x
```

I tried using `grep *` to grep everything but that didn't work, how can I make grep a noop in certain cases? Perhaps it is grep '*' instead of grep *?

Using `grep '*'` didn't seem to work either, seems to only capture some stderr but not stdout?

Comment: Do you mean, `grep . <somefile>` ?

Comment: Why do you need to use grep if you need everything?

Comment: `*` is not a valid regex.  If you want to grep for literal '*', use `grep -F '*'` which searches for strings, not regexes.

Comment: I don't know about you but this seems like a groovy question to me lulz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
grep ''
```